# Some companies charge a fee for using their credit card. What is this fee called?

Tags: credit-card, line-of-credit

I need to know what do they call this type of fee?

Comment: Are you asking about the companies that you're making a purchase from or the company that you got the card through?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is called a "convenience fee", but they could call it anything they want I guess. Depending on the [card issuer and state](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/credit-card-convenience-fees-cost-surcharges-1280.php), this practice may be against the rules for the merchant to do this (although less so than before 2013)

Comment: +1 for the 2013 note; I used to keep the MC/Visa rule listing noting that was against the Merchant Agreement in my wallet. Also, I've seen "surcharge" used as well.